# How to add onload() event into @section('content') of laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

Is possible to do this? For example I have this code:

```
@section('content' onload='MyFunction')
  <!--PAGE CONTENT...-->
  <div>
   <h1>Something...</h1>
   <select name="sel"></select>
  </div>
@endsection

<script type="text/javascript">

  function MyFunction(){

   obj = document.forms[0].sel;

   for (i=0; i<23; i++) {

    //A similar condition to onload() event.

  }
</script>
```

Or is it wrong of me to do that so? I'm working in Laravel and PHP. Or maybe using a Jquery function similar to the function in javascript.

Comment: No this is not possible.but you can use $('document').onready()

Comment: Why don't you just set the onload event in the layout'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must understand that `@Section` is a blade tag. Blade tags are processed inside PHP. Also, the blade syntax does not accept the parameter `onload` as you want.

Also, either on HTML/JS you can't use `onload` as you want.

You have two alternatives:

**1** - Put a script tag after the section:

```
@section('content')
  <!--PAGE CONTENT...-->
  <div>
   <h1>Something...</h1>
   <select name="sel"></select>
  </div>
  <script>
    // Note that this function must have been declared before
    // this script tag, otherwise it will log an error:
    // "Uncaught ReferenceError: MyFunction is not defined"
    MyFunction(); 
  </script> 
@endsection
```

In this solution, the function will be called right after the browser loads this piece of html, but other parts of the html may not be loaded yet.

**2** - Put a script tag watching for the `load` event on document:

```
<script>
    $(document).load(function() {
        MyFunction(); 
    });
</script>
```

The advantage of this method is that it will only be called after the entire page being loaded, so the order of the `<script>` tags doesn't matters (except that the jquery call must be after the jquery script tag.

Answer (score 0):

Or, if you don't want to use jQuery and go for the native approach, you can use:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  // do your stuff here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO is better if you divide HTML Markup and scripts using 2 sections eg:

```
 @section('content')
     <!--PAGE CONTENT...-->
     <div>
         <h1> Something ... </h1>
         <select name="sel"></select>
     </div>
     <script type="text/javascript">
     function MyFunction(){
         obj = document.forms[0].sel;
         for (i=0; i<23; i++) {
             //A similar condition to onload() event.
         }
     }     
    </script>
 @endsection
 @section('script')
     MyFunction();
     // every script here will run onload
 @endsection
```

and in your layout place both sections

```
 <main class="container">
      <section id="content">
           @yield('content')
      </section>
 </main>

 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            @yield('script')
        });
 </script>
```